# how to Clear the iPhone app cache

Tags: iphone

I am trying to browse a webpage using NSURLCOnnection. Everytime it is using cached data,its not getting latest webpage. How to clear the iPhone app cache.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :

You specify cache policy when you create your NSURLRequest object. Set the cachePolicy property to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData or use the initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval: initializer. See documentation on cache policy.

or

You can clear the cache explicitly using:

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

more links :

http://www.148apps.com/news/free-space-deleting-apps-cache-files/

http://www.ehow.com/how_4848193_clear-cache-file-iphone.html